# Position Animated Text to the Bottom Left of Div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

could someone please help me position this animated text to the bottom left corner of my div? If I need to change the way I implement the animated text I am all ears. I got the example I'm using from another Stack Overflow thread. I'm using Wordpress & Elementor.

The link to my website is:
http://stalone.flywheelsites.com/

The current code I am using is the following:

```css
.lyrics-container {
    margin: 75% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.lyrics{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87%;
}
.lyrics:nth-child(1){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;  
}


.lyrics:nth-child(2){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade{
    0%,50% {
      opacity: 0;
}
    100%{
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="lyrics-container">
  <p class="lyrics">I'm trying,<br>not to swim<br>into the deep,</p>
  <p class="lyrics">I will never<br>love again.</p>
  </div>
```

***Note: I did a quick margin hack for demonstration purposes, I know this isn't feasible and that is why I am here looking for help.***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your website this div is wrapped in another div

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a relative wrapper for the absolute positioned element. This is a common way of doing it. You may need to give the wrapper a certain height. For example 100vh or whatever you neeed.

I just added the bare minimum. So you will have to handle the rest of the styles.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
 }

.lyrics-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 75% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.lyrics{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87%;
}
.lyrics:nth-child(1){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;  
}


.lyrics:nth-child(2){
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade{
    0%,50% {
      opacity: 0;
}
    100%{
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper" >
     <div class="logo">Logo</div>
     <div class="lyrics-container">
        <p class="lyrics">I'm trying,<br>not to swim<br>into the deep,</p>
        <p class="lyrics">I will never<br>love again.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this works, I just needed to add a width of 100% to the .lyrics-container div so that the line breaks were as defined. I was just hoping there was a way other than using the margin 75% to force the positioning in the bottom left corner of the div. Is this the best way to achieve this, or is there something else better I can do? The main thing I don't like is how different viewports don't really position it to the bottom left corner consistently. I found this website: https://generalcondition.com/ I like how they do it, but I don't know how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` to align it to the bottom without affecting the rest of your components. More on `position`s [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
.lyrics-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lyrics {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87%;
}

.lyrics:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

.lyrics:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">Logo</div>
<div class="lyrics-container">
  <p class="lyrics">I'm trying,<br>not to swim<br>into the deep,</p>
  <p class="lyrics">I will never<br>love again.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using it like this within other elements on a real website may end up with unexpected results since there is no parent that is declared relative.

Comment: Very true, I noticed that. I did want to use the bottom:0; alignment instead of the margin 75% because it feels a little wonky to me.